# Sphinx sql field string

Tags: configuration, search-engine, sphinx

Installed the sphinx package on my Debian server but my config produces the following error when I try to run the indexer.

```
using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
ERROR: unknown key name 'sql_field_string' in /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf line 26 col 25.
FATAL: failed to parse config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'
```

The indexer should be fine  because I run the same configuration on my local development (osx), sphinx compiled version.

Look likes I do missing a package or something? Hope someone can help me out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The package you installed is almost certainly for a old version of sphinx. One that didnt have string attributes.

When you run indexer, it will print it version on the first line. Compere that to when you run indexer locally.

Can get a .deb file here...
http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/